# Generate header dynamically using xslt 2.0

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have xml source:

```
    <Report_Data>
          <Report_Entry>
             <Journal>
                  <Ledger>1<Ledger>
              </Journal>
           </Report_Entry>
          <Report_Entry>
             <Journal>
                  <Ledger>1<Accounts>
              </Journal>
               <Journal>
                  <Ledger>2<Accounts>
              </Journal>
           </Report_Entry>
    <Report_Data>
```

Based on the number of ledger returned, I want to create the columns. Based on the sample data source, the second report entry has the highest number of ledger returned, and so my header column should have 2:
Example expected output:

```
Ledger|Ledger
```

What I've done so far is

```
 <xsl:if test="count(Report_Data/Report_Entry/Journal/Ledger) > 1">            
            <xsl:for-each select="Report_Data/Report_Entry/wd:Journal/Ledger">
                <xsl:text>Ledger</xsl:text>
                <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each> 
        </xsl:if>
```

But the output is incorrect, it's returning 3 Column headers summing up all the ledger values returned.

```
Ledger|Ledger|Ledger
```

Can help how to determine the highest number of ledger values and then create columns based on that?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
  <xsl:template match="Report_Data">
      <xsl:value-of 
        select="Report_Entry[count(.//Ledger) = max(../Report_Entry/count(.//Ledger))]//Ledger/local-name()" separator="|"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks @Martin , can I ask how to change the header column label? e.g. From Ledger to Ledger_ID based on ur code? thanks

Comment: If you want a constant value then use `/'Ledger_ID'` instead of `/local-name()` in the last step; if the name is to be included use e.g. `/concat(local-name(), '_ID')` in the last step.